# Javascript - Insert variable as Object keys?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I read and tries everything, but I can't figure out how to do this simple thing.

Basically,

```
var obj = {
    price: 15
};
var foo = "price";

if(obj.[foo] == 15){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean `var foo = "price"`. In that case, just remove the dot: `if(obj[foo])`.

Comment: what do you want ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use bracket notations. But you're also not doing that correctly.

Let's say you had `var foo = 'price';` "price" is a key in `obj` but not its own variable, so you can't just say `var foo = price;` (an unset variable).

For bracket notation:

```
if(obj[foo] == 15){
    return true;
}
```

In this case you'd be saying "check to see if the price property of object foo is 15."

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable). *(not my dv)*